# Powershell: How to simply output date to DataGridView

Tags: arrays, powershell, datagridview, wmi

I'm having a real problem here.

Take this code:

`Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystemProduct -ComputerName summer  | Select Vendor,Version,Name,IdentifyingNumber,UUID`

I'm trying to get the above Get-WMIobject that has been piped into a Datagridview with the data output the same as you'd see it if it was run via the console directly.

For some reason, it keeps being outputted into the DatagridView, with the columns of Vendor, Version etc. showing what seems to be the directory path or some such data that I don't want.

Try it for yourself in a console, that how I want it to be outputted.

This is the datagridview I'm using:

```
$arrayt = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
  $global:target_active_d = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystemProduct -ComputerName $target_hostname.text | get-member Vendor,Version,Name,IdentifyingNumber,UUID
  $arrayt.AddRange($target_active_d)
  $target_output.DataSource = $arrayt
```

Please help

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$arrayt = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
  $global:target_active_d = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystemProduct -ComputerName $target_hostname.text | Select-Object Vendor,Version,Name,IdentifyingNumber,UUID
  $arrayt.Add($target_active_d)
  $target_output.DataSource = $arrayt
```

Comment: That hasn't worked. I get the error - "Cannot convert argument "0", with value: " etc.

Comment: Which line do you get the error on? Do you just want to output it to a nice formatted searchable grid? If so use Out-Gridview.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do. Ok, I'll give that a go and report back, thanks

Comment: I've tried it and although it's a good idea, it doesn't work as I've created my own GUI, out-gridview just exports it to a new window. I'm using a datagridview: $current_output = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$current_output.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,320)
$current_output.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,170)
$current_output.ColumnHeadersVisible = $true
$objForm.Controls.Add($current_output)

Comment: All that refers to $current_output. What you posted refers to $target_output.

Comment: Sorry, I should of mentioned, I am using two datagridviews with two different names. Currnt_hostname and target_hostname. Is there not a simple way to output to datagridview? Maybe using a foreach function?

Answer (score 0):

This code showed me the fields you selected in your Get-WmiObject code snippet:

```
Clear-Host
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objForm.AutoSize = $True
$current_output = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView 
$current_output.AutoSize = $True
$objForm.Controls.Add($current_output) 
$arraylist = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$arraylist.Add((Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystemProduct -ComputerName "." | Select-Object Vendor,Version,Name,IdentifyingNumber,UUID))
$current_output.DataSource = $arraylist
[void]$objForm.Activate()
[void]$objForm.ShowDialog()
[void]$objForm.Dispose()
```